# Unable to convert string to float in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a String with a number into a float.
I tried the following:

```
write_file($log . "temp=" . $temp . ".<br/>" , "public/files/log.txt" );
write_file($log . "temp type=" . gettype($temp) . "<br/>" , "public/files/log.txt" );
$flyt  = floatval("2.19");
write_file($log . "2.19 float =" . $flyt . ".<br/>" , "public/files/log.txt" );
$flyt  = floatval($temp);
write_file($log . "temp float =" . $flyt . ".<br/>" , "public/files/log.txt" );
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
temp float =0.
2.19 float =2.19.
temp type=string
temp=2.19.
```

When $temp is "2.19", why can't I get it to float?
I've tried several methods, none work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: As you can see in the outprint, $temp is a String with "2.19". I should be able to cast that to float

Comment: Your question is unclear I see no problem with converting string "2.19" to float

`var_dump((float)"2.19");
var_dump(floatval("2.19"));`

Comment: Works for me http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c559992e556de3adf63a3fad9a9451e4e81779b7 if there's any invisible character in your `$temp` variable before the numbers then it will break. Try `trim($temp)` beforehand

Comment: There might be some problem with the encoding type of the file

Answer (score 2):

Go through this Documentation:
[String Convertions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

This Should do that:

```
$flyt = (float) "2.19";
```

For *floatval* :

```
$string = '2.19';
$flyt  = floatval($string);
echo $flyt;
```

Have a look at [FloatVal Examples](http://php.net/function.floatval) too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use typecasting.

```
$StringVal = "10.12";   // $StringVal is String
$FloatVal = (float) $StringVal;   // $FloatVal is Float
```

You can use this function to convert string variable to float.

This function takes the last comma or dot (if any) to make a clean float, ignoring a thousand separators, currency or any other letter:

```
function tofloat($num) {
    $dotPos = strrpos($num, '.');
    $commaPos = strrpos($num, ',');
    $sep = (($dotPos > $commaPos) && $dotPos) ? $dotPos : 
        ((($commaPos > $dotPos) && $commaPos) ? $commaPos : false);

    if (!$sep) {
        return floatval(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $num));
    } 

    return floatval(
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, 0, $sep)) . '.' .
        preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", substr($num, $sep+1, strlen($num)))
    );
}
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

PTR when using **floatval()**:

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float.